# Text on Path for Direct2D

Tags: winapi, direct2d

I recently encountered this  SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- to hide the path, it is usually wrapped in a <defs> element -->
  <!-- <defs> -->
  <path
    id="MyPath"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50" />
  <!-- </defs> -->

  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath">Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Which renders in browsers like that:

[image]

Now in [Direct2D SVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/direct2d/svg-support?redirectedfrom=MSDN) this isn't supported.
Even if it was, what 's the math algorithm behind this? I want to implement it myself in C++ but I can't find any resource that describes a logic for it. I am already using a [custom Direct2D renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/how-to-implement-a-custom-text-renderer) but , given a path, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Essentialy, what I need is, when having a series of ID2D1Geometry's of Glyphs, to translate/rotate them properly to match the path in another ID2D1Geometry.

Edit: The best I 've got so far is this:

[image]

```
            float StartPoint = 0;
            // j.sPaths contains ID2D1Geometry for all letters, as rendered by GetGlyphRunOutline.
            for (size_t iip = 0; iip < j.sPaths.size(); iip++)
            {
                    if (g1) // The geometry in which to adjust the letters
                    {
                        nop();
                        D2D1::Matrix3x2F m1 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity();
                        D2F bnds = {};
                        j.sPaths[iip].pPath->GetBounds(m1, &bnds);
                        if (bnds.left > bnds.right)
                            continue;

                        // make sure this is at 0,0
                        float ExtraX = -bnds.left;
                        float ExtraY = -bnds.top;

                        auto wi2 = bnds.Width();
                        auto he2 = bnds.Height();
                        auto wi = wi2 / (float)vepXX.SizeCreated.cx; // vepXX.SizeCreated  = rendering area, Normalize everything to [0,1] because the geometry g1 is within [0,1].
                        auto he = he2 / (float)vepXX.SizeCreated.cy;


                        D2D1_POINT_2F StartPointOnThePath = {}, p0tv = {};
                        D2D1_POINT_2F EndpointOnThePath = {}, p1tv = {};
                        g1->ComputePointAtLength(StartPoint, m1, &StartPointOnThePath, &p0tv);
                        float Endpoint = StartPoint + wi;
                        g1->ComputePointAtLength(Endpoint, m1, &EndpointOnThePath,&p1tv);
                        float MidpointOnThePath = (EndpointOnThePath.x - StartPointOnThePath.x)/2.0f + StartPointOnThePath.x;

                        StartPoint = Endpoint;
                        if (oo)             StartPoint += oo->AddX; // Extra X option

                        float angle = 0;    
                        angle = (float)atan2(p1tv.y, p1tv.x);
                        float angled = angle * 180.0f / 3.1415f;
                        float xx = (MidpointOnThePath - wi/2)* vepXX.SizeCreated.cx; // convert to view
                        float yy = (EndpointOnThePath.y - he)* vepXX.SizeCreated.cy;    

                        D2D1_POINT_2F pr = {wi2/2.0f,he2/2.0f};
                        
                        auto xform = D2D1::IdentityMatrix();
                        // Translate the glyph to 0,0
                        xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(ExtraX, ExtraY);

                        // Rotate to put
                        xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(angled,{wi2/2.0f,he2/2.0f});

                        // Translate to position
                        xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(xx,yy);
                        
                        faa->CreateTransformedGeometry(j.sPaths[iip].pPath, &xform, &j.sPaths[iip].pPathX);
  // Draw the new geometry later.
                    }
```

Comment: You can 1) measure each glyph position using DWrite 2) use ID2D1PathGeometry1::ComputePointAndSegmentAtLength() to get points and normal for every glyph position (1st parameter is position on the path geometry) then 3) follow the rules here  https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextpathLayoutRules (or not...) to output glyphs one by one

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm trying. Current problem is that ComputePoint returns length as drawn by the curve, this means that the more curvy a bend is, the less "width" for the letter will be available. I'm working on it.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but font size is not determined by the path length, it just happens that this particular SVG path is computed to fit well with the default font-size value (which is 16px, CSS rules).

Comment: @SimonMourier I added some code. I think I have a Y vertical positioning problem.

Comment: I'm sorting it out. I should denormalize the geometry (which was normalized to 0,1) to full view width/height before I do calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fully working example, using [ID2D1PathGeometry1::ComputePointAndSegmentAtLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1pathgeometry1-computepointandsegmentatlength(float_uint32_constd2d1_matrix_3x2_f_float_d2d1_point_description)) that allows you to get points coordinates of a path from a `length` parameter. `length` represents the point on the path which is "at length distance" along this path from its start.

The sample code uses a custom [IDWriteTextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritetextrenderer) implementation which is used to render each glyph along the path. This sample implementation mostly implements `IDWriteTextRenderer::DrawGlyphRun` for the whole string, which in turns re-uses [ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawGlyphRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawglyphrun) for each glyph after appropriate translation and rotation.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <windows.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <winrt/base.h>

using namespace winrt;

com_ptr<ID2D1Factory1> _d2dFactory;
com_ptr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget> _renderTarget;
com_ptr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> _red;
com_ptr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> _black;
com_ptr<ID2D1PathGeometry1> _geometry;
com_ptr<IDWriteTextLayout> _layout;

wchar_t _phrase[] = L"Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

class Renderer : public IDWriteTextRenderer
{
public:
  STDMETHOD(DrawGlyphRun)(void* clientDrawingContext, // should be used to pass RenderTarget, Geometry, etc.
    FLOAT baselineOriginX, FLOAT baselineOriginY,
    DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE measuringMode,
    DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN const* glyphRun,
    DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN_DESCRIPTION const* glyphRunDescription, IUnknown* clientDrawingEffect
    )
  {
    auto advance = baselineOriginX;
    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < glyphRun->glyphCount; i++)
    {
      D2D1_POINT_DESCRIPTION desc;
      check_hresult(_geometry->ComputePointAndSegmentAtLength(advance, 0, nullptr, &desc));
      if (desc.endFigure) // path ends here, we could break
      {
        // continue with a small back out
        advance -= desc.lengthToEndSegment;
        check_hresult(_geometry->ComputePointAndSegmentAtLength(advance, 0, nullptr, &desc));
      }

      advance += glyphRun->glyphAdvances[i];

      // compute angle
      auto angle = M_PI_2 - atan2(desc.unitTangentVector.x, desc.unitTangentVector.y);

      // translate & rotate
      auto baseLineTx = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(0, glyphRun->fontEmSize - baselineOriginY);
      auto tx = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(desc.point.x, desc.point.y);
      auto rot = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation((FLOAT)(angle * 180 / M_PI));
      _renderTarget->SetTransform(baseLineTx * rot * tx);

      // draw 1 glyph
      DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN run = *glyphRun;
      run.glyphCount = 1;
      run.glyphAdvances = &glyphRun->glyphAdvances[i];
      run.glyphIndices = &glyphRun->glyphIndices[i];
      run.glyphOffsets = &glyphRun->glyphOffsets[i];
      _renderTarget->DrawGlyphRun(D2D1_POINT_2F(), &run, _black.get(), measuringMode);
    }

    _renderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::IdentityMatrix()); // make sure we come back to no transform
    return S_OK;
  }

  STDMETHOD(IsPixelSnappingDisabled)(void* clientDrawingContext, BOOL* isDisabled)
  {
    *isDisabled = TRUE;
    return S_OK;
  }

  // nothing is implemented except IUnknown
  STDMETHOD(GetCurrentTransform)(void* clientDrawingContext, DWRITE_MATRIX* transform) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  STDMETHOD(GetPixelsPerDip)(void* clientDrawingContext, FLOAT* pixelsPerDip) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  STDMETHOD(DrawUnderline)(void* clientDrawingContext, FLOAT baselineOriginX, FLOAT baselineOriginY, DWRITE_UNDERLINE const* underline, IUnknown* clientDrawingEffect) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  STDMETHOD(DrawStrikethrough)(void* clientDrawingContext, FLOAT baselineOriginX, FLOAT baselineOriginY, DWRITE_STRIKETHROUGH const* strikethrough, IUnknown* clientDrawingEffect) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  STDMETHOD(DrawInlineObject)(void* clientDrawingContext, FLOAT originX, FLOAT originY, IDWriteInlineObject* inlineObject, BOOL isSideways, BOOL isRightToLeft, IUnknown* clientDrawingEffect) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
  {
    if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown)) { *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this; return S_OK; }
    if (riid == __uuidof(IDWritePixelSnapping)) { *ppvObject = (IDWritePixelSnapping*)this; return S_OK; }
    if (riid == __uuidof(IDWriteTextRenderer)) { *ppvObject = (IDWriteTextRenderer*)this; return S_OK; }
    *ppvObject = nullptr;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
  }

  ULONG AddRef() { return 1; }
  ULONG Release() { return 1; }
};

Renderer _renderer{ };

void Render()
{
  _renderTarget->BeginDraw();
  _renderTarget->Clear(D2D1_COLOR_F(1, 1, 1));

  // draw geometry
  _renderTarget->DrawGeometry(_geometry.get(), _red.get(), 4);

  // draw phrase using our special render
  // with some start offset (250)
  // and some baseline offset (10)
  check_hresult(_layout->Draw(nullptr, &_renderer, 250, 10));
  check_hresult(_renderTarget->EndDraw());
}

void BuildGeometry(FLOAT width, FLOAT height)
{
  auto margin = 60.0f;
  width -= 2 * margin;
  height -= 2 * margin;
  if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
    return;

  _geometry = nullptr;
  check_hresult(_d2dFactory->CreatePathGeometry(_geometry.put()));
  com_ptr<ID2D1GeometrySink> sink;
  check_hresult(_geometry->Open(sink.put()));
  auto size = D2D_SIZE_F(width / 4, height / 2);
  sink->BeginFigure(D2D_POINT_2F(margin + width / 4, margin), D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);
  sink->AddArc(D2D1_ARC_SEGMENT(D2D_POINT_2F(margin + width / 4, margin + height), size));
  sink->AddLine(D2D_POINT_2F(margin + width * 3 / 4, margin + height));
  sink->AddArc(D2D1_ARC_SEGMENT(D2D_POINT_2F(margin + width * 3 / 4, margin), size));
  sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
  check_hresult(sink->Close());
}

void Resize(UINT width, UINT height)
{
  winrt::check_hresult(_renderTarget->Resize(D2D1_SIZE_U(width, height)));
  BuildGeometry((FLOAT)width, (FLOAT)height);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (uMsg)
  {
  case WM_PAINT:
  {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    Render();
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
  }

  case WM_SIZE:
    Resize(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    return 0;

  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
  wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.lpszClassName = L"App";
  RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

  auto hwnd = CreateWindow(L"App", L"App", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 600, 400, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

  // init some D2D & DWrite
  check_hresult(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, _d2dFactory.put()));
  check_hresult(_d2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd), _renderTarget.put()));
  check_hresult(_renderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(1, 0, 0), _red.put()));
  check_hresult(_renderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0, 0), _black.put()));

  com_ptr<IDWriteFactory> dwriteFactory;
  check_hresult(DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), (IUnknown**)dwriteFactory.put()));
  com_ptr<IDWriteTextFormat> format;
  check_hresult(dwriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(L"Times New Roman", nullptr, DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 50, L"", format.put()));

  // we want a straight line w/o limit
  check_hresult(dwriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(_phrase, lstrlen(_phrase), format.get(), FLT_MAX, 0, _layout.put()));

  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);
  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

With 250px start offset and 10px baseline offset:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @SimonMourier works. For each glyph you have to translate to the path using ComputePointAtLength from ID2D1Geometry, after scaling the geometry to actual view size.

```
                    D2D1_POINT_2F StartPointOnThePath = {}, p0tv = {};
                    D2D1_POINT_2F EndpointOnThePath = {}, p1tv = {};
                    auto xform3 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale((FLOAT)vepXX.SizeCreated.cx, (FLOAT)vepXX.SizeCreated.cy);

                    g1->ComputePointAtLength(StartPoint, xform3, &StartPointOnThePath, &p0tv);
                    float Endpoint = StartPoint + wi2;
                    g1->ComputePointAtLength(Endpoint, xform3, &EndpointOnThePath,&p1tv);

                    D2D1_POINT_2F MidpointOnThePath = {(StartPointOnThePath.x + EndpointOnThePath.x)/2.0f,(StartPointOnThePath.y + EndpointOnThePath.y) / 2.0f };
                    D2D_POINT_2F GlyphMidline = {bnds.MiddleX(),bnds.MiddleY()};

                    StartPoint = Endpoint;
                    float angle = 0;
                    angle = (float)atan2(p1tv.y, p1tv.x);
                    float xx = MidpointOnThePath.x;
                    float yy = MidpointOnThePath.y;
                    // Alignment options
                    if (ly && ly->YPos == -3)
                        yy -= he2/2.0f;
                    if (ly && ly->YPos == -1)
                        yy += he2 / 2.0f;
                    auto xform = D2D1::IdentityMatrix();

                    // Translate the glyph to 0,0
                    xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(ExtraX, ExtraY);

                    // Rotate to put
                    xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(angled);

                    // Translate to position
                    xform = xform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(xx,yy);
                    
                    faa->CreateTransformedGeometry(j.sPaths[iip].pPath, &xform, &j.sPaths[iip].pPathX);
```

[image]